# Wordpress Custom Import Plugin Not working

Tags: php, wordpress, import

I have a wordpress custom import plugin which was working fine, but for some reason it is not working in a new wordpress install [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz49yx2ra50v3lv/sjr-product-import.zip?dl=0). Plugin looks for two feed files barneys_feed.txt & barneyswarehouse_feed.txt (included with plugin) which should be configured in plugin settings page [Detailed Description](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofkizneohzt4ee6/product_import.docx?dl=0). On activation a custom table has to be created but not creating and on product run following is displayed in log:

```
[Tue Nov 22 18:28:08.931419 2016] [:error] [pid 11484] [client 38.140.212.19:64906] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to sjr\\product_import\\SJR_Product_Import::get_line() must be an instance of SplFileObject, null given, called in /nas/content/live/testwindow/wp-content/plugins/sjr-product-import/includes/class-sjr-product-import.php on line 334 and defined in /nas/content/live/testwindow/wp-content/plugins/sjr-product-import/includes/class-sjr-product-import.php on line 372, referer: http://testwindow.wpengine.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=sjr_product_import_settings
```

Not able to reach out plugin developers. Please help. Thanks.

**Update:**
Following is the error i am getting now.

```
 PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to sjr\\product_import\\SJR_Product_Import::get_line() must be an instance of SplFileObject, null given, called in /nas/content/live/testwindow/wp-content/plugins/sjr-product-import/includes/class-sjr-product-import.php on line 334 and defined in /nas/content/live/testwindow/wp-content/plugins/sjr-product-import/includes/class-sjr-product-import.php:372\nStack trace:\n#0 /nas/content/live/testwindow/wp-content/plugins/sjr-product-import/includes/class-sjr-product-import.php(334): sjr\\product_import\\SJR_Product_Import->get_line(NULL, 1)\n#1 [internal function]: sjr\\product_import\\SJR_Product_Import->csv_to_database()\n#2 /nas/content/live/testwindow/wp-includes/plugin.php(600): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#3 /nas/content/live/testwindow/wp-cron.php(117): do_action_ref_array('sjr_product_imp...', Array)\n#4 {main}\n thrown in /nas/content/live/testwindow/wp-content/plugins/sjr-product-import/includes/class-sjr-product-import.php on line 372, referer: http://testwindow.wpengine.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1480412579.4279830455780029296875
```

Comment: What steps have you taken so far to try to fix this yourself?

Comment: Try go to plugin settings and check the **Server path to import file 1** and **Server path to import file 2** paths; hit **Save Settings** even if you see the text boxes filled with values. Also check these file paths to exist at the path and your WP app has access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Something I find helpful for debugging these kinds of issues is looking at the stack trace of where your error is. You can print the stack trace at each of the [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) at each of the locations you call `get_line` to see what is on the stack when you get the failed call.

I don't have your project up at this time, but it looks like your `$file` object is no longer in scope (and therefore null) for this call to `get_line`

```
foreach( $lines as $line_item ){
    if( $file_name != $line_item['file'] ){
        $file_name = $line_item['file'];
        $basename = basename( $file_name );

        // get columns
        $file = new \SplFileObject( $file_name, 'r' );
        $file->setFlags( \SplFileObject::READ_CSV );
        $file->setCsvControl( "\t", " " );

        // get first row with column names
        $first_row = $this->get_line( $file, 0 );
    } // You lose scope on $file here

    $row = $this->get_line( $file, $line_item['line_number'] - 1 ); // <-- This one is the likely cause
```

You should do two things here:

1. Define $file before the if statement (likely as `$file = null`)
2. Handle the case of still having a null `$file` object after the if statement and before the problem `get_line` call.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you, that at some point, the `get_line` function of `sjr\product_import\SJR_Product_Import` gets instead of an instance of `SplFileObject` just a `null`.

I'm guessing the `get_line` function looks something like this:
`public function get_line(SplFileObject $file) { /* do some stuff */ }`

What you can either do (assuming you wrote that code on your own), is to change the function to something like this:

`public function get_line(SplFileObject $file=null) { /* do some stuff */ }`

telling PHP that besides the object, you also accept null as a default value. In that case, you would have to update your function, to check if the given variable is null. You can check this for example with

`if (!is_null($file)) {
    /* every thing is fine */
} else {
    /* there was an error, maybe write it to a error log */
}`

A completely guess from my side, as the error states, that the location contains `/nas/` I'm assuming, that the PHP code is run on a NAS and has some drives mapped, from which you try to import some stuff periodically, as the import is started by a cron job. Maybe one of those mapped drives somehow lost the connection and therefore PHP wasn't able to read the files. But as I said, that's just a wild guess. To "debug" this, you could check the status of the mapped drives manually when the cron job is run and see, if the problem still happens. Another thing could be, that PHP (or more precise, Apache or Nginx) doesn't have rights to access those files/shares.